# Javascript to locate all angular js grid in a webpage

Tags: angularjs

I have been using Extjs where we have Ext.componentquery to locate any element. Do we have something like that in angular js as well?

Scenario :

I am looking some equivalent of
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('fieldxtype')

Comment: It depends, what are you trying to do with the controls when you find them?

Comment: Basically i trying to automate a website built on angularjs. The end scenario is i want to locate a table cell and perform click operation. Like in ext js once we find the control then we can access its store to find the value and perform the click.

Comment: Angular dosn't "work" this way. You might make it but it would probably cause performance issues. You could set some parent directive that will manage the gridsApi's or something. I asdume you mean ui-grid.